# How to allow a User only access their own data in Spring Boot / Spring Security?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have some rest api like this:

```
/users/{user_id}
/users/{user_id}/orders
/users/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}
```

How I must secure them? every user must see only her/his data, But admin can see all of them.

How & What I must implement in Spring Security that User by Id == 1 can't see data of user by Id == 2 and vice versa, expect users by role admin that can see all?

Do I check before every method User Id in session is equail with user_id param passed to api? is there a better way?

p.s: I use JWT by spring security.

Comment: I highly recommend Chapters 16 and 17 of _Spring Security in Action_ by Laurențiu Spilcă (2020). He also has a YouTube playlist [here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEocw3gLFc8XRaRBZkhBEZ_R3tmvfkWZz).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In any `@Controller`, `@RestController` annotated bean you can use `Principal` directly as a method argument.

```
    @RequestMapping("/users/{user_id}")
    public String getUserInfo(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userId, Principal principal){
        // test if userId is current principal or principal is an ADMIN
        ....
    }
```

If you don't want the security checks in your `Controller`s you could use *Spring EL* expressions.
You probably already use some build-in expressions like `hasRole([role])`.

And you can write your own expressions.

1. Create a `bean`

```java
    @Component("userSecurity")
    public class UserSecurity {
         public boolean hasUserId(Authentication authentication, Long userId) {
            // do your check(s) here
        }
    }
```

2. Use your expression

```java
    http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/user/{userId}/**")
          .access("@userSecurity.hasUserId(authentication,#userId)")
        ...
```

The nice thing is that you can also combine expressions like:

```java
    hasRole('admin') or @userSecurity.hasUserId(authentication,#userId)
```

---

UPDATE for **Spring Security 6.x**

adapt `UserSecurity`

```java
@Component
public class UserSecurity implements AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> {

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier authenticationSupplier, RequestAuthorizationContext ctx) {
        // get {userId} from the request
        Long userId = Long.parseLong(ctx.getVariables().get("userId"));
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) authenticationSupplier.get();
        return new AuthorizationDecision(hasUserId(authentication, userId));
    }
    public boolean hasUserId(Authentication authentication, Long userId) {
        // do your check(s) here
        
    }

}
```

and use this with requestMatchers

````java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, UserSecurity userSecurity) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                auth -> {
                    auth
                        .requestMatchers("/users/{userId}/**").access(userSecurity)
                        ....;
                }
        )....;
        return http.build();
    }

```
````

Comment: Can I do it with AOP?

Comment: In case you are struggling with the custom expression, add "**@Component("userSecurity")**" above "**public class UserSecurity{**" line

Comment: But "In any @Controller, @RestController annotated bean you can use Principal directly as a method argument." is not working. Principal is just `null`

Comment: @ACV  yes.... the Principal should be accessible ref: [principal-in-restcontroller](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/principal-in-restcontroller)

Comment: Thank you @DirkDeyne you created the example specially for demonstration. Nice. So how do you request that endpoint so that the Principal is not null? Is it a request header or something else? How does Spring populate that object?

Comment: @ACV  here is a good overview [spring.io guide: spring-security-architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture), you should look at the `Web Security` part

Comment: What is the `authentication` object? What it stores?

Comment: @user123145152323 The Authentication object in the SecurityContext: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use @PreAuthorize on the service interface. If you have a custom userdetails object then you can do it easily.
In one of my projects I did it like this:

```
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasAuthority('ADMIN')"
        + "or authentication.principal.equals(#post.member) ")
void deletePost(Post post);
```

BTW this is in a service interface.  You have to make sure to add the right annotations to get preauthorize to work.

Answer (score 2):

You should first choose your security strategy,
What you need names "Row Filtering", one of Authorization Concepts of 3A( Authentication, Authorization,Audit ) Concepts.

If you want to implement comprehensive solution, take a look at :

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html
```

Spring ACL completely covers concepts like "Row Filtering", "White-Black List", "Role Base Authorization", "ACL Inheritance", "Role Voter", ....

Otherwise you should save the owner per business case you want to be secured and filter them in your Service Layer.

Answer (score 0):

We can create an annotation like `@IsUser` and use it with the controller method.

Example :

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_USER')" + "and authentication.principal.equals(#userId) ")
public @interface IsUser { }
```

Comment: It should be `authentication.principal.username.equals(#userId)`