# How filter all methods by user ID?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I'm using:

- `spring-boot-starter-web`
- `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`
- `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`
- `spring-boot-starter-security`

and with `spring data-rest` I created REST API. Every entity has property `userId`. How can I use it to restrict all repository methods (e.g.: `findAll()`, `save()`, ...)?

I want that only owner can see, edit, and delete his data.

Comment: have a look here: [how-to-allow-a-user-only-access-their-own-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712724/how-to-allow-a-user-only-access-their-own-data-in-spring-boot-spring-security/51713982#51713982)

Comment: The case there is different. I don't have user id in HTTP path :/

Comment: Only way in my case is to filter all entities by user id with is inside entity.