# How to permit access to resource only for specific user

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to allow access to this method only for admins or users, whose id is the same as its own. So basically John with ID 1 won't be able to access Matt's orders with ID 2. I've been trying to achieve this with principal.id, but it says that id id near principal cannot be resolved. Is there any way to achieve what I want? Thank you.

```
@GetMapping("/users/{userId}/orders")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or #userId == principal.id")
List<Order> getOrdersByUserId(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    log.info("Request to get user's orders by userId: {}", userId);
    if (!userRepository.existsById(userId)) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException(userId);
    }
    return orderRepository.findByClientId(userId);
}
```

Comment: I think this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713982/14056755

Comment: Thanks. The post was informative, but nonetheless my code did work actually, but near `principal.id` it says  `Cannot resolve property or method 'id' (dynamic property?)`. Not sure why and how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `authentication.principal.id` instead of `principal.id`, the warning will go away.