# How can I restrict a user from view / edit records thorught JWT token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I am using the `JWT` concept in `Spring Boot`  with `Spring Security`. Everything works promising, System is able to generate a Token and validate it with spring security.

The issue with the current implementation is Anyone "user X" can update/view the record of "User Y" using his/her own token. It's just not about the user Info. For example:

There are two tables in the Database:

1. User
2. Car

I am keeping `userId` in the `car` entity.

Right now "User x" can access the car details of "User Y" using the "CarID". How should I restrict "User X" to do any kind of transaction in a database which belongs to him/her only.

I followed the following options

1. `@PreAuthorize`
2. Adding `User-Agent`

But none of them are helping me out. Any hint would be appreciable.

Comment: get the token userId from token and validate car.userId = token.userId in query.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712724/how-to-allow-a-user-only-access-their-own-data-in-spring-boot-spring-security

Comment: @GnanaJeyam That will happen on the Dao level, I want to put into the JWT level.

Comment: A good concept would be to use `Multi-Tenancy`, With this you completely seperate the users. Each of them have a seperate DB or Schema. And anytime the user signs in with his JWT, he connects to his corresonding DB and this way, his data is isolated from other Users.